# Sort an array based on the element on inside array of strings

Tags: typescript

I have an array that has a list of strings arrays

```
 [['A', 'B'],
 ['B', 'A'],
 ['B', 'B'],
 ['A', 'A']]
```

and I need to sort it to be:

```
 [['A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['B', 'B'],
 ['B', 'A']]
```

I am having trouble finding a good way how to sort as the inside array might have more than two Items. and when the first row has similarities with the rows behind, like row number n.
The final array should look similar to
And the final array should be:

```
 [['A', 'A'],
 ['', 'B'],
 ['B', 'B'],
 ['', 'A']]
```

Comment: Explain what you need that for

Comment: I want to create some kind of tree with the elements
as I explained above I might have more than 2 elements inside the array and I need to make sure that it works for more elements, and I also need to check the similar rows and remove similar elements from array as in the last array

Comment: Then maybe you need a result of `{A: ['A', 'B'], B: ['A', 'B']]}` and the order does not matter?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I need to order the arrays not to order the element inside the array

Comment: I am using rowValues =  rowValues.sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)); to sort it but i am not sure if it is correct or not. in case of more elemeents

Comment: If the arrays are all of strings with only one character then you should be able to use localeCompare.